# Replacing elemnts of an R matrix using a location matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, location, subset

In the following example i am trying to replace some elements of a two columns matrix m using a two column matrix containing row and columns positions.

bbb

> ```
>       [,1] [,2]
>  [1,]   21    1
>  [2,]   15    2
>  [3,]   16    2
>  [4,]   17    2
>  [5,]   18    2
>  [6,]   19    2
>  [7,]   20    2
>  [8,]   21    2
>  [9,]   22    2
> [10,]   23    2
> [11,]   24    2
> [12,]   25    2
> [13,]   26    2
> [14,]   27    2
> [15,]   13    3
>
>
> m = matrix(nrow=30,ncol=4)
> > m[as.matrix(bbb)] = matrix(1:15,ncol=1)
> > sum(!is.na(m))
> [1] 15
> > 
> > m[,1:3]
>       [,1] [,2] [,3]
>  [1,]   NA   NA   NA
>  [2,]   NA   NA   NA
>  [3,]   NA   NA   NA
>  [4,]   NA   NA   NA
>  [5,]   NA   NA   NA
>  [6,]   NA   NA   NA
>  [7,]   NA   NA   NA
>  [8,]   NA   NA   NA
>  [9,]   NA   NA   NA
> [10,]   NA   NA   NA
> [11,]   NA   NA   NA
> [12,]   NA   NA   NA
> [13,]   NA   15   NA
> [14,]   NA   NA   NA
> [15,]   NA    2   NA
> [16,]   NA    3   NA
> [17,]   NA    4   NA
> [18,]   NA    5   NA
> [19,]   NA    6   NA
> [20,]   NA    7   NA
> [21,]    1    8   NA
> [22,]   NA    9   NA
> [23,]   NA   10   NA
> [24,]   NA   11   NA
> [25,]   NA   12   NA
> [26,]   NA   13   NA
> [27,]   NA   14   NA
> [28,]   NA   NA   NA
> [29,]   NA   NA   NA
> [30,]   NA   NA   NA
> ```

The last element that should be modified is at position (13,3), but instead, the modification is done at position (12,2) which does not appear in the positions matrix bbb. Any help ?

The behavior is even weirder in the following example..

```
> bbb
    [,1] [,2]
21    21    1
56    15    2
57    16    2
58    17    2
59    18    2
60    19    2
61    20    2
62    21    2
63    22    2
64    23    2
65    24    2
66    25    2
67    26    2
68    27    2
95    13    3
96    14    3
97    15    3
98    16    3
99    17    3
100   18    3
> m = matrix(nrow=30,ncol=4)
> m[as.matrix(bbb)] = 1:20
> sum(!is.na(m))
[1] 16
> 
> m
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [7,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [8,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [9,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[10,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[11,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[12,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[13,]   NA   15   NA   NA
[14,]   NA   16   NA   NA
[15,]   NA   17   NA   NA
[16,]   NA   18   NA   NA
[17,]   NA   19   NA   NA
[18,]   NA   20   NA   NA
[19,]   NA    6   NA   NA
[20,]   NA    7   NA   NA
[21,]    1    8   NA   NA
[22,]   NA    9   NA   NA
[23,]   NA   10   NA   NA
[24,]   NA   11   NA   NA
[25,]   NA   12   NA   NA
[26,]   NA   13   NA   NA
[27,]   NA   14   NA   NA
[28,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[29,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[30,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 1):

We need to use a `vector`

```
m[as.matrix(bbb)] <- 1:15
```

-output

```
> m
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [7,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [8,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [9,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[10,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[11,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[12,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[13,]   NA   NA   15   NA
[14,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[15,]   NA    2   NA   NA
[16,]   NA    3   NA   NA
[17,]   NA    4   NA   NA
[18,]   NA    5   NA   NA
[19,]   NA    6   NA   NA
[20,]   NA    7   NA   NA
[21,]    1    8   NA   NA
[22,]   NA    9   NA   NA
[23,]   NA   10   NA   NA
[24,]   NA   11   NA   NA
[25,]   NA   12   NA   NA
[26,]   NA   13   NA   NA
[27,]   NA   14   NA   NA
[28,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[29,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[30,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

-second example

```
m2 <- matrix(nrow=30,ncol=4)
m2[as.matrix(bbb2)] = 1:20
```

output

```
> m2
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [7,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [8,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [9,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[10,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[11,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[12,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[13,]   NA   NA   15   NA
[14,]   NA   NA   16   NA
[15,]   NA    2   17   NA
[16,]   NA    3   18   NA
[17,]   NA    4   19   NA
[18,]   NA    5   20   NA
[19,]   NA    6   NA   NA
[20,]   NA    7   NA   NA
[21,]    1    8   NA   NA
[22,]   NA    9   NA   NA
[23,]   NA   10   NA   NA
[24,]   NA   11   NA   NA
[25,]   NA   12   NA   NA
[26,]   NA   13   NA   NA
[27,]   NA   14   NA   NA
[28,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[29,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[30,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

#### data

```
bbb <- structure(c(21, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 
27, 13, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3), .Dim = c(15L, 
2L))
m <- matrix(nrow=30,ncol=4)
bbb2 <- structure(c(21L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L), .Dim = c(20L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("21", "56", "57", 
"58", "59", "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", 
"95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100"), NULL))
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't change for me even with a vector...

Comment: @Badih Are you using the same original `matrix` (`m = matrix(nrow=30,ncol=4)`) for changing or the one you already changed?

Comment: I use the same original matrix; and i even updated the R version, and used the same code

Comment: @Badih I can't reproduce the issue.  I have the data showed in my post and the output

Comment: @Badih I assume that you used the same `bbb` and `m`.

Comment: yes, the same code replacing the matrix by the vector 1:15.

Comment: @Badih Can you please get the `dput(bbb)`

Comment: here it is for the first example : structure(c(21, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 
27, 13, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3), .Dim = c(15L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(c("21", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "61", 
"62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "95"), NULL))

Comment: @Badih it still gives the correct output i.e. `m[13,3]#
[1] 15`

Comment: These are base R functionalities, which shouldn't differ.  Try on a fresh R session without any other objects

Comment: @ akrunI updated R, and removed dimnames from bbb but still the same result. The second exmple i added to the question is even weirder

Comment: @Badih it didn't matter with the dimnames for me as both are giving the same output

Comment: @Badih tried your second example as well, couldn't reproduce your issue

Comment: It's really surprising especially since I have the same behavior on different machines under Linux and Windows

Comment: @Badih I was using `macOS` with `R 4.1.2`

Comment: @Badih if your version is `R 4.1.3`, then could that be a bug?

Comment: I have tried both versions on windows and version 4.1.2 on ubuntu

Comment: @Badih i installed the `R 4.1.3` and tried on mac, it gives the same output for me.  Maybe your windows R version have some bug

Comment: thanks. I found where the problem came from. Location indices were real numbers. Rounding them resolved the problem.